# how to set another list box by day of week?

Tags: c#

i'm making study planner program with C# window form.
So, i made set of plan by list box. And, i want it to set another plan by day of weeks.(ex, Monday plans are 'go shopping' & 'doing homework', Tuesday plans are 'Visiting grandmother home' ... like this)

I tried to work it with visible and invisible setting. But, it was failed. 
And I tried googling with this problem. No even Before, I couldn't find adequate answer.

I want to make database by days of week and showing it with another days of week.
Could you recommend the way i can set of plans by days of week??

---

this is partial source for plans with list box.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace consistency
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_remove2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbox_1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }

            string str = lbox_1.SelectedItem as string;
            lbox_1.Items.RemoveAt(lbox_1.SelectedIndex);
        }

        private void btn_add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbox_1.Items.Add(tbox_1.Text);
            tbox_1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void tbox_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lbox_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### lbox_1 is list for previous plan. and btn_add2 is button for add plan and btn_remove 2 is button for remove plan.

this is my whole code for modifying plans pop-up without days of week.
I want to differ list box elements with days of week....

Comment: Can you provide source for us to see what you have so we can correctly assist you with this issue.

Comment: here is some code. plz help me.... I'll try everything for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the whole class?

Comment: wait i'll adding

Comment: You need to clear the second listbox and repopulate it when the first listbox's selected index changes in the `SelectedIndexChanged` method.